# Rails 6 accessing credentials does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to set up a Stripe payment form for a Rails 6 project, and I am not able to access my stripe secret keys. I am getting an error `` NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) `` What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I did

1. Edit my credentials.yml.enc - Type this in the console `EDITOR="code --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit`
2. Added my secret keys to credentials.yml.enc

   ```
   some_variable: secret_stuff
   development: 
     stripe:
       stripe_public_key: fake_key
       strip_secret_key: fake_key
   ```
3. Closed the file and double checked it saved my code by opening up the file to verify it was saved (it was)
4. Open up rails console and typed in `Rails.application.credentials.some_variable`
   I expected `secret_stuff` but I got `nil`.
   Typed in `Rails.application.credentials.development[:stripe][:stripe_public_key].`
   I expected `fake_key` but I got `` NoMethodError (undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass) ``

WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

I can't display a credit card form, and I just want to get this up and running so I can charge people and become a millionaire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably accessing credentials environment wrong, this should work:

```
Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:stripe][:stripe_public_key]
```

`credentials.development` => `credentials[Rails.env.to_sym]` (so you are accessing current environment varbiales)

Comment: "Read the doc" they say. Well where in the docs is ```Rails.env.to_sym``` ?
Thanks for this.

Comment: Nope this actually does not work either. Can't even deploy, `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` won't work. Work around to precompile for production is using dig method. Sure, then can deploy but that ain't working either. It's a waist. 2 days now. Very frustrating how they closed this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do `Rails.application.credentials.stripe[:stripe_public_key]`

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to call it as far as I know:

```
Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:service][:credential_you_are_looking_for]
```

OR

```
Rails.application.credentials.dig(:production, :service, :credential_you_are_looking_for)
```

this example would have this structure in the credentials.yml.enc file

```
production:
   service:
       credential_you_are_looking_for: "some credential string here"
```

Pay attention that the nesting should be as in the example above the nesting defines what belongs where and if it's the same level this would not work.